# KDE: Show App Menus on all displays

Tags: kubuntu, kde, appmenu

In a 3 monitor setup, I'm trying to make the KDE desktop (in Kubuntu 19.10) act as much like the Unity 7 desktop as possible.

The specific issue I'm currently having, is that the **menu bar** of applications does not appear at all unless I'm on my laptop's built-in monitor. When I have an application's window on one of the other two monitors, the application menu cannot be seen (even if I hit the alt-key). 
Currently, to access these menus I'm having to drag the window over to the default monitor just long enough to use the application menu and then drag it back to the desired monitor, after I'm done.

How can I get each application's application-menus to show no matter which monitor is displaying that window?

Comment: I figured this out. Right-Click on the desktop of the additional monitor and click "Add Panel" > "Application Menu Bar". In my opinion the bars should be on by default (for each monitor connected) and advanced users should have the burden of removing them if they don't like the panel being there. As a new KDE user, I can tell you for certain that current defaults of not having the "Application Menu Bar" (at all) on multiple monitors doesn't make much sense. The new user doesn't know how to access an application's main menu at all.

Comment: I'm trying to advocate that All panels should show on all monitors by default, in a bug report to KDE, [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=416852).

Comment: I also submitted this request to Kubuntu, [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/kdelibs/+bug/1861088).

Comment: I also donated money to the KDE project, [here](https://kde.org/donations). The project looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

- Minimize all windows
- Right-Click on the desktop of any monitor and click "Add Panel" > "Default Panel".
- Right-Click on the new panel, check "Edit Panel", click "Screen Edge" and drag&drop to your desired place on any of your screens.